# Java properties - no more get/set in names?

Tags: java, coding-standards, properties

I don't `getFoo`/`setFoo` naming *convention*, that is so spread that it become a standard. Instead, I am using more and more just: `foo()` and `foo(value)` for reading and setting value. I also see this trend in some libraries like VertX.

While this is fine when I work on my projects; should I do the same for the 3rd party library that I want to publicly release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the get/set convention exists is because it identifies methods as "properties." Properties have different semantics than other methods:

1. They serve as a place to put validation logic.
2. They are intended to *return quickly.*
3. You have better interoperability with tools and frameworks that also follow the convention, such as Javabeans.

If you don't need any of these things. then by all means, come up with your own unique convention.

**Further Reading**
[How important are naming conventions for getters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1389244/102937)

Comment: By not following one convention, that does not mean that I don't need or use what you stated. Other languages does not have this silly contract. However, the #3 is the main reason why I agree with what you said.

Comment: In C#, the concept of properties is *baked into the language.*  A property in C# looks like this: `public string Foo { get { // return _foo; } set { _foo = value; }`

Comment: Yeah, I would like to see this in Java, like in other languages. In other words, not to be a convention anymore.

Comment: But that doesn't mean you stop using the convention altogether.  It just means that you have the discipline to do it without the language forcing you to do it,

Comment: I agree. However, after years of doing this, I just stopped loving using 'get' and 'set' in method names. I don't like the fact I am being 'forced' by convention. Don't get me wrong, recently I think a lot about how languages are actually very... limited. Thanx.

Comment: @igor the reason java doesn't have an easy way to define getters and setters is because getters and setters are supposed to be rare. You're not supposed to pull the contents of an object out and look at it

Comment: @RichardTingle tell the to any `User` object out there :))) Just kidding, can you elaborate: "You're not supposed to pull the contents of an object out and look at it"?

Comment: @RichardTingle: I think that is an academic claim that fails spectacularly in the real world.

Comment: @Igor absolutely true, my programs are full of getters and setters, but I don't put them in "just because" or lightly. If it was a part of the declaration people would put them in automatically